# Need register in expression

Tags: assembly

```
title pak name show in uppercase
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg db "pakistan",'$'
upp db ?
siz = $-msg+1
.code
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov bx,offset msg
mov dx,offset upp
mov cx,siz
l1:mov al,byte ptr[bx]
sub al,32
mov byte ptr[dx],$
inc bx
inc dx
loop l1
mov ah,9
int 21h
main endp
End main
```

while doing this program an error is coming
**Error** up.asm(17) Need register in expression

Answer (score 0):

mov byte ptr[dx],$

is line 17.

`$` is not a register, but this argument has to be a register.

`$` means 'the current location` and is not a byte.

You probably want `AL` in place of `$` here.

Answer (score 0):

And now here is my comment posted as an answer:
DX can not be used as an addressregiser within brackets[]. Only BX, SI, DI (defaultsegment DS) and  BP, SP (defaultsegment SS).